# How can you use scalacheck to verify if some generated code from a function is correct?

Tags: scala, obfuscation, scalacheck, correctness

Hi so im completely new to scalacheck. 
So im building an obfuscator, and I want to check if the obfuscated code which i generate is correct. My function changes a while loop to a switch, so is there some way i can check if the structure of the switch is how i wanted it to be made?

Answer (score 0):

For all valid inputs, check if the generated function generates the same output as the obfuscated function. For an arbitrary function, you'll have to write your own generator.